# How to convert "," to string[]

Tags: arrays, string, f#

I would like to pass a string containing a delimiter, like `","` to an F# function, but the caller is getting an error indicating that because `","` is not a `string[]`.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let csv_fileH = initCsvLib "test1.csv" ","
```

The library code below is written to create its own delimiter, but it would be nice to pass the delimiter so pipe and other delimited files could be read.

```
namespace Toa.csv_lib
.
.
.
(* Contains various necessary open statements *)

[<AutoOpen>]
module csv_lib =

    let initCsvLib fn =
        let csv_delim = ","
        let csv_fileH = new TextFieldParser(fn:string)
        csv_fileH.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited |> ignore
        csv_fileH.SetDelimiters(csv_delim) |> ignore
        csv_fileH
```

What is the best way to convert a string type to string[]? I've been looking on Microsoft's site and other places as well.

Comment: Note that your `...Property = Value |> ignore` line is probably not doing what you want. Try `...Property <- Value` (set property vs. compare its value and discard true/false).

Answer (score 6):

If the method `SetDelimiters` expects an array of many delimiters (as the name also suggests) you can pass `[|","|]` and it should work.

Probably they did that way because one might eventually need to pass multiple delimiters, i.e.

```
[|","; "|"|]
```

Comment: Is there a reason -- and commas don't work 'cause I tried -- that the list is bracketed by vertical bars?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus `[||]` is the syntax for an array https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/arrays

Comment: Yes, because without the brackets it would be an F# list, not an Array.